# tibco BW XA transcation

Tags: tibco

We have Tibco BW Component deployed as Ec2 instance on top of AWS.Sometimes the XA Transcation manager are giving the below error.

129:0javax.transaction.NotSupportedExceptionBaseTransaction.checkTransactionState - [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.alreadyassociated] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.alreadyassociated] thread is already associated with a transaction!

We are using Tibco Businessworks XA Transcation manager This error seems to occur as a thread is already associated with a transaction and attempts to start a second transaction.When checking with the DBA it was confirmed that there is no hanging/indount transcation in the DB.

Did any body faced similar issue and what should be the way out here